# HTTP Requests and Responses on Discord without inviting an official discord bot to that server

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js, discord.py, discord.net

I have a list of Discord servers and channels I want a program to listen to. If specific keywords are found in text messages send in this channel, I want the program to contact the sender of the message with a standard text DM. It is basically a targeting bot. I assume that since the servers will not invite my bot if it was a discord bot, that I will need an external program using HTTP Requests and responses. Does this work with discord? Do you have any ideas how to implement my idea?

Comment: You can't listen to messages in a server without actually being in that server. That would be extremely poor privacy practice on discords end. Additionally, you can't send a message to a user unless you share a server with that user. So, no, none of what you want would work.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I want to do something similar; have a bot just listen to messages in a channel and server that I am a part of, but that the owner doesn't want to invite bots to

Answer (score 3):

The only way to see messages in a server is to be in that server, which also applies to bots, so **you'll have to have them add it**. Please also note that using the Discord API to make "user bots" (user accounts that act as bots) or to send unwanted direct messages is **against their [Terms of Service](https://discord.com/terms)**.

With that in mind, you have two options:

---

### Using the Gateway

When you're connected to the Discord gateway, you receive `MESSAGE_CREATE` events whenever a new message is sent in a place your bot can see. There are many libraries that allow you to do that, like [discord.js](http://discord.js.org/). Once you have it installed, listening for messages is as simple as that:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

---

### Querying the REST API

You can also obtain messages with the [Get Channel Messages](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages) endpoint, but I wouldn't recommend that as you'd have to send one request for each channel your bot is in, and repeat it every X minutes/seconds to account for new messages. This would easily hit their ratelimit if your bot happens to be in many servers.